# Call service and return data undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger

It may have some stupid things but I can't figure it out soon.

I use SwaggerService to return data but get undefined.

```
import {SwaggerService} from '../../services/swagger.service';

export class TestComponent implement OnInit {
  public mydata:Object;

  constructor(public readonly service: SwaggerService)
  {
     this.service = this.service['GetData'].get().subscribe(
      data=>{
          this.mydata['data']=data;
      },
      error=>console.error(error)

     );
   }
}
```

The thing is `data` returns an array with detail values. But `this.mydata['data']` returns an array but no data, it is undefined.

The service comes from .net controller. I am sure there is data and I verified it in chrome debugger.

Do I have to do some mapping?

Comment: show us your service, please\

Comment: can you add a ````console.log(data);```` before your assign ````data```` to ````this.myData['data']````? What do you get in your console? If it is ````undefined````, please show us your service.

Comment: `console.log(data)` does have real data. But `console.log(this.myData['data'])` not.

Comment: @nash11 is going in the right direction. You should *never* use `Object`, @Bigeyes you should read [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html) on the Do's and Don't with Types. That should help clear it up for you.

Comment: Change `this.mydata['data']=data;` to `this.mydata = { data };` Your instance variable is undefined, so this will define and set the `data` attribute/value at the same time.

Comment: Also, as @Narm pointed out, you really shouldn't type things to `Object`. Even if you don't read the linked article, `Object` is not really helpful or semantic from a typings standpoint.

Comment: @Narm,do you mean using `object` instead of `Object`? lowercase object type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have not initialized your `mydata` variable. You have declared `mydata` as an `Object` but it will initially have a value of `undefined` until you assign it a value.

Try initializing `mydata` to an empty object. That should fix your problem.

**Edit**: As @Narm mentioned in the comments and as shown in the link she provided, use the non-primitive `object` type instead of `Object`

```
public mydata: object = {};
```